# How to clean up server disk space (without breaking any sites)? And figure out which apps are using how much RAM (via the terminal)

Tags: php, terminal, digital-ocean, droplet

I am using RunCloud on top of a DigitalOcean droplet, and my web apps (in total) use only 2.2GB.

I want to downgrade my droplet, but I need to clear as much disk space as possible (as well as check which web apps are using how much RAM).

How do I check all of that via the terminal?

[image]

Comment: You might want to head over to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and ask there.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... The only way I can think to nicely get memory usage is perhaps to use xdebug. It keeps track of the function calls and how much memory they consume, lets you see how well code is performing in general.

Install xDebug, enable profiling xdebug.profiler_enable = 1, set xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/some/path. Then use QCacheGrind to visualise it.

OR ... memory_get_peak_usage() could maybe be used to log memory usage at the end of each request, then I guess you would also need to work out max average number of requests for a vhost and that should give a ballpark.

Also you could ask this on https://serverfault.com/ - stack overflow, but for infrastructure stuff ;)

Comment: Hmm, the furthest I've gotten was installing xDebug via the terminal. I have no idea how to do those last two steps.

Comment: Its in the php.ini file, should already be in there and just a case of uncommenting/amending values. Depending how Apache/PHP is configured may need an Apache Restart for PHP to pick the changes up... I'd only enable the profiler for a period long enough to gather as much info as you think you'll need, as it does slow down execution!